# How do I make vim abbreviations work?

Tags: vim

I can define new abbreviations no problem: e.g.

```
:ab Lunix Linux
```

defines an "Lunix" as an abbreviation for "Linux", as confirmed by the list which appears when I execute `:ab`.

In a plain text file, such as an empty buffer, this expands correctly, but with
some filetypes neither SPACE nor CTRL-] seem to work.

Is there a setting or mapping which might be getting messed up by some of my filetype plugins?

There's probably a really obvious answer to this, but I haven't found it hunting through the `:help` documentation yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you have installed LaTeX-Suite/the IMAP plugin? It may interfere with mappings and abbreviations.

You may also want to check whether any of the four timeout related settings have been changed.

Comment: Yes, turns out IMAP was getting in the way even in non-LaTeX files. I'll have to duplicate any abbreviations I want to use with IMAP() calls as well.

Comment: Not necessary duplicate. If IMAP is always active, you can just write your abbreviations to use IMAP. If not, the easier way would be to write a command that tests `exist('*IMAP')` to uses either `iabbr` or `IMAP()`.

Comment: I am having the same difficulty. Can you please tell me how do I make abbreviations use IMAP?

Comment: @MahbubAlam, I haven't used explicitly it in ages. You could have a look at a function I use to abstract the way I define insert-mode mappings in case IMAP is detected: https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-brackets/blob/master/autoload/lh/brackets.vim#L390